# Julia JuMP feasibility slack of constraints

Tags: julia, mathematical-optimization, julia-jump

In Julia, by using JuMP am setting up a simple optimization problem (MWE, the real problem is much bigger).

```
model = Model()
set_optimizer(model, MosekTools.Optimizer)
@variable(model, 0 <= x[1:2])
@constraint(model, sum(x) <= 2)
@constraint(model, 1 <= sum(x))
@objective(model, Min, sum(x))
print(model)
```

Which gives this model:

```
Min x[1] + x[2]
Subject to
 x[1] + x[2] ≤ 2.0
 -x[1] - x[2] ≤ -1.0
 x[1] ≥ 0.0
 x[2] ≥ 0.0
```

I optimize this model via `optimize!(model)`.

Now, obviously, the constraint `x[1] + x[2] <= 2` is redundant and it has a feasibility slack of "3". My goal is to determine all the constraints that have slacks larger than 0 and display the slacks. Then I will delete those from the model.

To this end, I iterate over the constraints which are not variable bounds and print their values.

```
for (F, S) in list_of_constraint_types(model)
    # Iterate over constraint types
    if F!= JuMP.VariableRef #for constraints that 
        for ci in all_constraints(model, F, S)
            println(value(ci))
        end
    end
end
```

However, because I print the `value` of the constraints, I get the left-hand sides:

```
1.0
-1.0
```

I want to instead see the slacks as

```
0
3
```

How may I do this? Note that I am not necessarily interested in linear programs, so things like `shadow_value` is not useful for me.

---

Based on the accepted answer, I am adding a MWE that solves this problem.

```
model = Model()
set_optimizer(model, MosekTools.Optimizer)
@variable(model, 0 <= x[1:2])
@constraint(model, sum(x) <= 2)
@constraint(model, 1 <= sum(x))
@constraint(model, 0.9 <= sum(x))
@objective(model, Min, sum(x))
print(model)
optimize!(model)
constraints_to_delete = vec([])
for (F, S) in list_of_constraint_types(model)
    if F!= JuMP.VariableRef
        for ci in all_constraints(model, F, S)
            slack = normalized_rhs(ci) - value(ci)
            if slack > 10^-5
                push!(constraints_to_delete, ci)
                println(slack)
                #delete(model, ci)
            end
        end
    end
end

for c in constraints_to_delete
    delete(model, c)
end

print(model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this (hot off the press) tutorial: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/dev/tutorials/linear/lp_sensitivity/.

Although focused on LPs, it shows how to compute slacks etc using `normalized_rhs(ci) - value(ci)`.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Why "normalized" though?

Comment: And second question (sorry): does this give slack regardless whether the constraint is \leq or \geq?

Comment: See the documentation: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/reference/constraints/#JuMP.normalized_rhs. It will give the slack, but maybe with a - sign if it's the opposite inequality

Comment: thank you for your answer. In that case I think we would need something like `normalized_value`. Do you think there is something similar? Many thanks!